# Group or summarize table with count condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

For the Table Below:

[image]

I want to make a table like this - Calculate the numbers of "YES" for each Customer

[image]

Thanks in Advance :)

SUMMARIZE('f_Alla_Produkter_för_varje_Kund','f_Alla_Produkter_för_varje_Kund'[Kundnr],'f_Alla_Produkter_för_varje_Kund'[DAC + 1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMMARIZE() was the right idea. Here's your **Calculated Table** expression:

```
Grouped Table = 
FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Customer],
        "Count of Yes/No", 
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS('Table'),
                'Table'[Yes/No] = "Yes"
            )
    ),
    [Count of Yes/No] <> BLANK()
)
```

[image]